# How to resolve ValueError: You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method that includes input_ids, but you provided ['label']

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, peft

I am working on sentiment analysis using the IMDb dataset and a GPT-2-based model. This is a toy project to understand PEFT and LORA as well as get some experience with the Huggingface library.

This is what I've tried out:

```
from datasets import load_dataset

splits = ["train", "test"]
ds = {split: ds for split, ds in zip(splits, load_dataset("imdb", split=splits))}

from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
# GPT-2 Tokenizer doesn't have a padding token.
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

def preprocess_function(examples):
    """Preprocess the imdb dataset by returning tokenized examples."""
    tokens = tokenizer(examples['text'],padding='max_length',truncation=True)
    return tokens


tokenized_ds = {}
for split in splits:
    tokenized_ds[split] = ds[split].map(preprocess_function, batched=True)


model2 = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    num_labels=2,
    id2label={0: "NEGATIVE", 1: "POSITIVE"},  # For converting predictions to strings
    label2id={"NEGATIVE": 0, "POSITIVE":1},
)
model2.config.pad_token_id = model.config.eos_token_id

from peft import LoraConfig
from peft import get_peft_model
lora_config = LoraConfig("lora_gpt2", fan_in_fan_out=True,)
lora_model = get_peft_model(model2, lora_config)

trainer_lora = Trainer(
    model=lora_model,
    args=TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="./data/sentiment_analysis2",
        learning_rate=2e-3,
        # Reduce the batch size if you don't have enough memory
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
        num_train_epochs=5,
        weight_decay=0.01,
        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
        save_strategy="epoch",
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
    ),
    train_dataset=tokenized_ds["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_ds["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer_lora.train()
```

When I run this code, Im getting the following error and have had some difficulty debugging the issue:

```
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:3018, in PreTrainedTokenizerBase.pad(self, encoded_inputs, padding, max_length, pad_to_multiple_of, return_attention_mask, return_tensors, verbose)
   3016 # The model's main input name, usually `input_ids`, has be passed for padding
   3017 if self.model_input_names[0] not in encoded_inputs:
-> 3018     raise ValueError(
   3019         "You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method "
   3020         f"that includes {self.model_input_names[0]}, but you provided {list(encoded_inputs.keys())}"
   3021     )
   3023 required_input = encoded_inputs[self.model_input_names[0]]
   3025 if required_input is None or (isinstance(required_input, Sized) and len(required_input) == 0):

ValueError: You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method that includes input_ids, but you provided ['label']
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this and haven't been able to find many examples for this online and was hoping the SO community could help out.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the LoRA model changes the name of the column expected from label, to labels.

In order to fix it, you need

```
# LoRA takes in "labels", not "label" so we need to rename the 
# training and testing sets
train_lora = tokenized_ds['train'].rename_column('label', 'labels')
test_lora = tokenized_ds['test'].rename_column('label', 'labels')
```

Also needed was the TaskType in the config:

```
LoraConfig(
r=8, 
lora_alpha=32,
target_modules=['c_attn', 'c_proj'],
lora_dropout=0.1,
bias="none",
fan_in_fan_out=True,
task_type=TaskType.SEQ_CLS
)
```